# #TenderfootSpiral

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, geography

[image: #TenderfootSpiral]

Clues:

Two hikers on an incline arrow with numbers.
Hiker 1 says: 38.548493. Hiker 2 says: -105.998749.

Sequence: Hiker  17711  Hiker  0  377  0  144  1  10946  233  987  0  2584  6765  75025

Hiker = _1_1

Instructions: Name That Singer

_ _ S _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Comment: Just a question, what font do you use for your puzzles?

Comment: @poco The title is Steady Hand OTF 700. I found it with "What Font is dot com". (700 is the weight, in this case meaning bold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is..

> SUSANBOYLE

The first thing we look at

> ...is the numbers. The numbers are a part of the Fibonacci numbers. Taking the numbers' nth terms (0 = 1, 1 = 1, 2 = 1, 3 = 2 and so on) and doing the A1Z26 cipher, will yield svsanalbumparty. This also is a reference to the title, as for the word "spiral", as in "Fibonacci Spiral"

> **EDIT NOTE:** The hikers are equal to a number with the digits ?1?1 in the Fibonacci sequence. 4181 is the only number.

Here's the rest of the solution.

> Looking at "svsanalbumparty", I see the phrase "an album party" there. Searching "an album party" in google, the autofill suggests "an album party meme". From there I looked at the search results and I found the meme page for **SUSAN BOYLE**. The title is also a reference to the meme because "susanalbumparty" was also a hashtag.